# the key is already associated with an element of this collection vba loop for

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop

In VBA loop For...Next

My problem is that I am trying to do a Loop

for For j = 1 to NumofPac
...........
....
next

but the system is showing me a warning about "test". What is the best way to fix this?

code as below

```
Sub CreateShiptest()

' Declare variables
Dim obj As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim currentDateSave As String
Dim UserName, Password, isRequested As String
Dim requestFilename, responseFilename As String

'partshipment
Dim plannedShippingDateAndTime As New Dictionary
Dim unitOfMeasurement As New Dictionary

Dim content As New Dictionary
Dim pickup As New Dictionary
Dim outputImageProperties As New Dictionary
Dim typeCode As New Dictionary
Dim NumA As String
Dim ShipTime As String

'collection
Dim imageOptions() As New Collection
ReDim imageOptions(50)
Dim inimageOptions As New Dictionary


Dim customerReferences() As New Collection
ReDim customerReferences(50)
Dim incustomerReferences As New Dictionary


Dim accounts() As New Collection
ReDim accounts(50)
Dim inaccounts As New Dictionary


'partpackage
Dim packages() As New Collection
ReDim packages(100)
Dim inpackages() As New Dictionary
ReDim inpackages(100)
Dim weight As New Dictionary
Dim dimensions() As New Dictionary
ReDim dimensions(100)


TotalRows = Sheets("ShipmentDetail").Range("B4:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count

currentDateTime = Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD")


' Create an object
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")



'GetValueShipmentDetails
plannedDate = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd" & "T" & "hh:mm:ss") & "GMT+00:00"


'PickUp
  PUisRequested = False
  PuCloseT = "17:00"
  PULocation = "reception"
  
  

'account
  TypeC = "shipper"
  NumA = "561111111"

'imagePro
  prinDPI = 300
  encodFormat = "pdf"

'imageOp
  WaybillType = "waybillDoc"
  WaybillTempl = "ARCH_8X4"
  WaybillReq = True
  
For i = 4 To TotalRows + 3

    
'contentinfo
ConisCustomsDeclarable = False
Condescription = "test"
Conincoterm = "DAP"
Conunit = "metric"


'packages
NumofPac = 3
pweight = 1
'Pdimension
Plength = 1
Pwidth = 1
Pheight = 1




' Add data to the object
'ShipmentDetails
'HeaderPlanshipdate
obj.Add "plannedShippingDateAndTime", plannedDate

'PickUp
obj.Add "pickup", pickup
    pickup.Add ("isRequested"), PUisRequested
    pickup.Add ("closeTime"), PuCloseT
    pickup.Add ("location"), PULocation



'account
obj.Add "accounts", accounts(i)
accounts(i).Add inaccounts
inaccounts.Add ("typeCode"), TypeC
inaccounts.Add ("number"), NumA

'imagePro
obj.Add "outputImageProperties", outputImageProperties
    outputImageProperties.Add ("printerDPI"), prinDPI
    outputImageProperties.Add ("encodingFormat"), encodFormat


'imageOp
outputImageProperties.Add "imageOptions", imageOptions(i)
    imageOptions(i).Add inimageOptions
    inimageOptions.Add ("typeCode"), WaybillType
    inimageOptions.Add ("templateName"), WaybillTempl
    inimageOptions.Add ("isRequested"), WaybillReq

'ContentDetail
obj.Add "content", content
    content("isCustomsDeclarable") = ConisCustomsDeclarable
    content("description") = Condescription
    content("incoterm") = Conincoterm
    content("unitOfMeasurement") = Conunit
    
    
'ContentPackages
content.Add "packages", packages(i)



packages(i).Add inpackages(i)

** For j = 1 To NumofPac

inpackages(i).Add "weight", pweight
inpackages(i).Add "dimensions", dimensions(i)
dimensions(i).Add "length", Plength
dimensions(i).Add "width", Pwidth
dimensions(i).Add "height", Pheight
   
  Next j**

' Convert the object to a JSON string
jsonReq = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(obj)
Debug.Print jsonReq


'Send the API request
obj.Remove "plannedShippingDateAndTime"
obj.Remove "pickup"
pickup.Remove "isRequested"
pickup.Remove "closeTime"
pickup.Remove "location"



obj.Remove "accounts"
'accounts.Remove inaccounts
inaccounts.Remove "typeCode"
inaccounts.Remove "number"

'imagePro
obj.Remove "outputImageProperties"
    outputImageProperties.Remove "printerDPI"
    outputImageProperties.Remove "encodingFormat"


'imageOp
outputImageProperties.Remove "imageOptions"
'imageOptions.Remove inimageOptions
inimageOptions.Remove "typeCode"
inimageOptions.Remove "templateName"
inimageOptions.Remove "isRequested"


'ContentDetail
obj.Remove "content"
 

'ContentPackages
 content.Remove "packages"
    inpackages(i).Remove "weight"
    inpackages(i).Remove "dimensions"
    dimensions(i).Remove "length"
    dimensions(i).Remove "width"
    dimensions(i).Remove "height"
Next

End Sub
```

Expect to be able to loop through a package according to its quantity.
This means that you expect to be able to use a looping construct, such as a for loop, to iterate over the items in a package a certain number of times. This will allow you to access each item in the package in turn and perform operations on it as needed.

Answer (score 2):

The same keys are being added to `inpackages(i)` and `dimensions(i)` for each iteration of `j`.

```
    For j = 1 To NumofPac

        inpackages(i).Add "weight", pweight
        inpackages(i).Add "dimensions", dimensions(i)
        dimensions(i).Add "length", Plength
        dimensions(i).Add "width", Pwidth
        dimensions(i).Add "height", Pheight

    Next j
```

I assume thet `j` should be used instead of `i`.

```
    For j = 1 To NumofPac

        inpackages(j).Add "weight", pweight
        inpackages(j).Add "dimensions", dimensions(i)
        dimensions(j).Add "length", Plength
        dimensions(j).Add "width", Pwidth
        dimensions(j).Add "height", Pheight

    Next j
```